# How to find the parent USB device of a serial port under macOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, usb, iokit

Here is how I was trying to enumerate all serial ports found on a Mac, and traverse up the device node tree to find the parent USB device for USB-serial adapters:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>
#import <IOKit/serial/IOSerialKeys.h>
#import <IOKit/usb/IOUSBLib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        CFMutableDictionaryRef keywordDict = IOServiceMatching(kIOSerialBSDServiceValue);
        io_object_t port = 0;
        io_iterator_t iterator = 0;
        kern_return_t result = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, keywordDict, &iterator);
        if (result)
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to find any serial ports.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        while ((port = IOIteratorNext(iterator)))
        {
            @autoreleasepool
            {
                NSMutableArray<NSDictionary *> *array = [NSMutableArray array];
                CFMutableDictionaryRef dict = NULL;
                result = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(port, &dict, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
                if (!result)
                    [array addObject:CFBridgingRelease(dict)];

                io_object_t parent = 0;
                io_object_t parents = port;
                while (IORegistryEntryGetParentEntry(parents, kIOServicePlane, &parent))
                {
                    result = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(parent, &dict, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
                    if (!result)
                        [array addObject:CFBridgingRelease(dict)];

                    if (parents != port)
                        IOObjectRelease(parents);
                    parents = parent;
                }

                NSLog(@"0x%08lx = %@", (uintptr_t)port, array);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However while this code can find all serial ports (both USB-serial adapters and the Super IO one on my Hackintosh,) the traverse up the IOService tree isn't working. Help? Target OS is macOS 10.13.6.

#### Edit

Here is the output for one of my USB-Serial adapters:

```
2018-08-18 19:05:39.860794+0800 lstty[98738:5197725] 0x00002a07 = (
        {
        CFBundleIdentifier = "com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily";
        IOCalloutDevice = "/dev/cu.usbmodem1751";
        IOClass = IOSerialBSDClient;
        IODialinDevice = "/dev/tty.usbmodem1751";
        IOGeneralInterest = "IOCommand is not serializable";
        IOMatchCategory = IODefaultMatchCategory;
        IOProbeScore = 1000;
        IOProviderClass = IOSerialStreamSync;
        IOResourceMatch = IOBSD;
        IOSerialBSDClientType = IOModemSerialStream;
        IOTTYBaseName = usbmodem;
        IOTTYDevice = usbmodem1751;
        IOTTYSuffix = 1751;
    }
)
```

Here is the `ioreg -itrc IOSerialBSDClient -w0` output for the same device:

```
+-o Root  <class IORegistryEntry, id 0x100000100, retain 15>
  +-o iMac14,2  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOPlatformExpertDevice, id 0x100000110, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (51894 ms), retain 45>
    +-o AppleACPIPlatformExpert  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOPlatformExpert:IODTPlatformExpert:IOACPIPlatformExpert:AppleACPIPlatformExpert, id 0x100000111, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (41509 ms), retain 50>
      +-o PCI0@0  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOPlatformDevice:IOACPIPlatformDevice, id 0x10000013e, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (41377 ms), retain 54>
        +-o AppleACPIPCI  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOPCIBridge:AppleACPIPCI, id 0x100000216, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (41332 ms), retain 31>
          +-o XHC@14  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOPCIDevice, id 0x1000001f0, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (35582 ms), retain 11>
            +-o XHC@14000000  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:AppleUSBHostController:AppleUSBXHCI:AppleUSBXHCIPCI:AppleUSBXHCILPT:AppleUSBXHCILPTH:AppleUSBXHCILPTHB, id 0x10000023d, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (35072 ms), retain 1249>
              +-o HS10@14a00000  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:AppleUSBHostPort:AppleUSBXHCIPort:AppleUSB20XHCIPort, id 0x100000277, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (22180 ms), retain 17>
                +-o IOUSBHostDevice@14a00000  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUSBNub:IOUSBDevice, id 0x100007a40, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1604 ms), retain 31>
                  +-o AppleUSB20Hub@14a00000  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:AppleUSBHub:AppleUSB20Hub, id 0x100007a4e, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1600 ms), retain 23>
                    +-o AppleUSB20HubPort@14a10000  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:AppleUSBHostPort:AppleUSBHubPort:AppleUSB20HubPort, id 0x100007a52, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (964 ms), retain 17>
                      +-o IOUSBHostDevice@14a10000  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUSBNub:IOUSBDevice, id 0x1000082bb, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (323 ms), retain 32>
                        +-o AppleUSB20Hub@14a10000  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:AppleUSBHub:AppleUSB20Hub, id 0x1000082d4, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (316 ms), retain 23>
                          +-o AppleUSB20HubPort@14a12000  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:AppleUSBHostPort:AppleUSBHubPort:AppleUSB20HubPort, id 0x1000082d8, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (269 ms), retain 17>
                            +-o ComboDebug USB Serial@14a12000  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUSBNub:IOUSBDevice, id 0x10000837e, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (268 ms), retain 28>
                              +-o IOUSBHostInterface@1  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUSBNub:IOUSBInterface, id 0x100008390, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (259 ms), retain 8>
                                +-o AppleUSBACMData  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOSerialDriverSync:AppleUSBACMData, id 0x1000083a0, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 6>
                                  +-o IOModemSerialStreamSync  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOSerialStreamSync:IOModemSerialStreamSync, id 0x100008417, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 6>
                                    +-o IOSerialBSDClient  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOSerialBSDClient, id 0x100008418, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 5>
                                        {
                                          "IOClass" = "IOSerialBSDClient"
                                          "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily"
                                          "IOProviderClass" = "IOSerialStreamSync"
                                          "IOTTYBaseName" = "usbmodem"
                                          "IOSerialBSDClientType" = "IOModemSerialStream"
                                          "IOProbeScore" = 1000
                                          "IOCalloutDevice" = "/dev/cu.usbmodem1751"
                                          "IODialinDevice" = "/dev/tty.usbmodem1751"
                                          "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
                                          "IOTTYDevice" = "usbmodem1751"
                                          "IOResourceMatch" = "IOBSD"
                                          "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
                                          "IOTTYSuffix" = "1751"
                                        }
```

Comment: How about some debug output from the traversal loop (for example `IORegistryEntryGetName` and `IOObjectGetClass`) for one of the ports where you're expecting to find a USB device. Then post the corresponding output from `ioreg -itrc IOSerialBSDClient` so we can see where they diverge.

Comment: @pmdj Added the output for one device. The walk never went up deep enough to reveal the USB device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with the early termination is the exit condition for your loop:

```
     while (IORegistryEntryGetParentEntry(parents, kIOServicePlane, &parent))
```

`IORegistryEntryGetParentEntry()` returns a `kern_return_t` - `KERN_SUCCESS` is 0, so this means the `while` condition evaluates to false and the loop never runs. Try

```
     while (KERN_SUCCESS == IORegistryEntryGetParentEntry(parents, kIOServicePlane, &parent))
```

Comment: The line worked like this: `while (!IORegistryEntryGetParentEntry(parents, kIOServicePlane, &parent))` I managed to dump the same level of detail and more from the loop. Now it is just finding the USB device and extract information.

Comment: Yes, yours is functionally equivalent to my suggestion. (I just prefer the clarity of mine, especially given that your original notation made the bug non-obvious.)

Comment: I have to admit that I wrote that non-obvious code out of habit from smaller device programming where every clock cycle counts. Some compilers emit different code for `if (!func()) {}` and `if (func() == 0) {}` and the former is usually a few instructions shorter.

Comment: @MaxthonChan Modern versions of clang and GCC emit identical code for the 2 variants if any optimisations are enabled: https://godbolt.org/z/vYWAnI

Comment: I had to deal with MPLAB XC8 v1.35 for a while back then, and that thing is not a derivative of either. Also the version of GCC 4.3.5 often used for AVR processor.